# Using bluetooth in java

Tags: java, audio, bluetooth

I'm attempting to write a Java application that will open up the device it is run on to receiving audio over Bluetooth and then playing that audio.

I looked up the JavaDoc for javax.bluetooth, frankly I'm a little confused by it, but while importing javax.bluetooth it failed to compile, So I'm not sure whats going on.

This is what I have so far if it helps:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.obex.*;
import javax.bluetooth.*;

public class BluetoothConnection{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DiscoveryListener alpha;
    startInquiry(777, alpha);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is 'startInquiry()' defined? You are not using a static import method nor is it local. Method are either static, called on the class, or regular member methods called on an instance of the class. Besides yoiu are not creating the DiscoveryListener (and chances are it's an interface you should implement...) This is java you know.. not C.

Comment: Oh, Didn't notice that. I changed it around a few times, I had it declared as javax.bluetooth.startInquiry(777, alpha) the numbers were random just trying to provoke a response out of the compiler. No matter how I have it configured though it tells me that: package javax.bluetooth does not exist.

Comment: javax.bluetooth is not embeded the default jdk. You need to get the library somewhere (both the API jar and/or some vendor implementation like http://bluecove.org/ ). And the BT hardware of course...

Comment: I see, Thanks! That really helps :)